# Calling javascript OnClientClick handler before crosspage postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm new to SO and fairly new to ASP.NET.

I have a LinkButton with an OnClientClick event, which I would like to execute some code before doing a crosspage postback.

This seems to work--I am able to retrieve the value from the next page--however, when I click "View" the HiddenField value is set to "Edit". I did some testing and it seems that *all* of the javascript functions are being called, regardless of which button is clicked. "Edit" is the last value set, so I am always retrieving the value "Edit" from my second page.

Javascript:

```js
function viewfunc(control) {
    <% hidden.Value = "View"; %>
    <% hiddenpanel.Update(); %>
    return true;
}

function editfunc(control) {
    <% hidden.Value = "Edit"; %>
    <% hiddenpanel.Update(); %>
    return true;
}
```

Form:

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView Id="gridview1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True">
        <Columns>

            // Data fields here...

        <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="viewlabel" runat="server" Text="View" OnClientClick="if(!viewfunc(this)) return false;" PostBackURL="~/NextPage.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="editlabel" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClientClick="if(!editfunc(this)) return false;" PostBackURL="~/NextPage.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>  
        </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>    
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="hiddenpanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server">
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Id='hidden' Value='Empty' />
        </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Note: I would have preferred to call these functions as codebehind functions, but I couldn't find a way to execute the codebehind after the click event but before the postback.

Thanks for any and all suggestions!

Comment: You should understand the ASP.NET page life cycle, how to write javascript, what is ViewState in order to successfully accomplish this with complete understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
function viewfunc(control) {
    document.getElementById('<% hidden.ClientID %>').value = "View";
    return true;
}
```

And

```
function editfunc(control) {
    document.getElementById('<% hidden.ClientID %>').value = "Edit";
    return true;
}
```

Those should update your hidden field, and then trigger the updatepanel update event.

When you have something like `<% hidden.Value = "View"; %>` this will simply run, Asp.net will not care it is inside a javascript function. I don't think you need to tell the `UpdatePanel` to 'Update' after the function is done, I think if you just leave it without that, it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed `<% hidden.ClientID %>` to `<%=hidden.ClientID %>` and it's working~
Thanks for the good explanation as well.